# How to stop ngOnInit shooting on route change?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-router

I have this kind of implementation of routing in my website:

```
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: CabinetComponent,
    canActivate: [PrivateRouterGuard],
    data: {section: MainComponent}
  },
  {
    path: 'settings/:page',
    component: CabinetComponent,
    canActivate: [PrivateRouterGuard],
    data: {section: SettingsComponent}
  }
```

As you can see both /home and /settings/account for example have same component to display and section inside cabinet is transferred as a component object in data property and is being displayed inside CabinetComponent in this way:

```
<ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="routeComponent"></ng-container>
```

routeComponent here is a variable, that contains this transferred in data component to display.

My point and aim is to make one-time initialization when user is entering his cabinet and I've thought, that ngOnInit will do it to me, BUT AFTER EVERY ROUTE CHANGE, despite the fact, that routing component is not changing and stays CabinetComponent, ngOnInit inside CabinetComponent shoots every time I change route. I should stop this. Any Ideas?

Comment: This is done using children routing https://dev.to/jwp/please-help-me-understand-child-routing-in-angular-3agb

Comment: Yes! Exactly what I needed! Thank you!